# Python3 - XPath query does not return entire list from site when attempting to get data attribute values

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, elementtree

- Using Python3 to scrap website. Using xpath query to retrieve desired string.
- There looks to be about 19 elements that the data should query, however dataId variable only diplays one entry.
- I am also trying to get the data-eventid, that is in the /tr tag itself (image included). However the code now seems to exclude this html tag

Is my understanding wrong?

```
import requests
from lxml import etree

url = 'http://www.forexfactory.com/calendar.php?'
date = {'day':'feb9.2017'}

resp = requests.get(url,date)

tree = etree.HTML(resp.text)
dataId = tree.xpath("string(//*[@id='flexBox_flex_calendar_mainCal']//tr[contains(@class,'calendar__row calendar_row')])")
```

[xpath query result in firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nf2ez.jpg)

[debug values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JU0bc.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `string()` function around your XPath was receiving the text of the first elemnet. If you remove that, then you can get a collection of the queried elements. From there, you can iterate over the elements and access the `data-eventid` property on the element's [`attrib` property](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.attrib):

```
tree = etree.HTML(resp.text)
for row in tree.xpath("//*[@id='flexBox_flex_calendar_mainCal']//tr[contains(@class,'calendar__row calendar_row')]"):
    print(row.attrib['data-eventid'])
```

Also, since you're always accessing the element's `data-eventid` attribute, it may be safer to only select elements with `data-eventid` attributes by adding `[@data-eventid]` to your XPath:

```
tree = etree.HTML(resp.text)
for row in tree.xpath("//tr[contains(@class,'calendar__row calendar_row')][@data-eventid]"):
    print(row.attrib['data-eventid'])
```